# Where can I find a full websocket example easily working with easyphp an/or wamp?

Tags: php, websocket

Also, my requirements :

- archive containing all the code so I just have to drag and drop it to easyphp
- any kind of example will do the job (chat, game...)

I'm not a script kiddie. The way I work when attempting to learn a new techno is to retro engineer an example. So far, I haven't found annything meeting the 2 requirements.

*(Please don't downvote even if you think I'm too lazy)*

---

While any answers pointed me to a great internet resource, I manage to implement a pretty great example. It's a whiteboard.

If you are interested, here are the links :

- [My blog entry about it](http://marcelsite.heroku.com/posts/13-Having-fun-with-websocket)
- [The github repo](https://github.com/marcelfalliere/Websocket-php-whiteboard)
- [The video demontrating it.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANqHZg5vh7o)

Just wanted to share. Any questions, I be glad to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dont now about the easyphp-part, but Nuttuts has a nice tutorial called "Start Using HTML5 WebSockets Today". Find it here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/